# Basic Dynamic memory and pointers to arrays

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float **daily_rainfall;
    float new_rainfall;
    // daily_rainfall has been assigned an array of 12 float arrays. Each element of the array
    // has been initialized to point to an array of 31 floats. This structure represents a year's
    // worth of rainfall.
    //
    // new_rainfall has been intialized to some hidden value.
    //
    // Set the float corresponding to April 12th (the 12th day of the 4th month)
    // to equal the value currently stored in new_rainfall.

    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to c. I tried to figure it out but it didn't work.

```
(*daily_rainfall)[4][12] = new_rainfall;
```

I think it makes sense but i'm getting errors.

Comment: Do you have to use malloc() or can you use an array?  The title says "Dynamic".

Comment: Also, c is 0 based so month 4 is MAY.

Comment: @JustinJ. Oh yea. It should be  daily_rainfall[3][11] = new_rainfall;  Thanks!

Comment: If you want meaningful help, please show how you allocated the array(s), how you assigned it to `float **daily_rainfall;` and describe the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're having a double pointer to float, you would access contents of the array as follows:

```
daily_rainfall[3][11] = new_rainfall;
```

Comment: You need to allocate the memory before trying to use it.

Comment: "daily_rainfall has been assigned an array of 12 float arrays."

Comment: @Shiro I tried that but unfortunately, it's not correct

Comment: I've seen that you are looking for April 12th and edited my answer accordingly.